# How to emit YAML in Ruby expanding aliases

Tags: ruby, yaml, alias, psych

I am looking for a way to emit YAML files avoiding the use of aliases (mostly for simplified human readability). I think extending `Psych::Visitors::Emitter` or 
`Psych::Visitors::Visitor` is the way to go, but I cannot actually find where Ruby decides whether to dump an anchor in full, or reference it with an alias.

I wouldn't even mind if the anchors were used repeatedly (with their &...... references), I just need to expand aliases to the full structures.

I am aware of similar questions being asked in the past, but:

- [Ruby YAML write without aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981128/ruby-yaml-write-without-aliases) remained unanswered
- [Is it possible to emit valid YAML with anchors / references disabled using Ruby or Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016220/is-it-possible-to-emit-valid-yaml-with-anchors-references-disabled-using-ruby) gave answer for Python but not for Ruby

Comment: `YAML.dump` uses [`YamlTree`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.4/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb) to serialize your Ruby data to Yaml. The alias handing is done by the inner [`Registrar`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.4/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L15-L37) class and it simply [emits an alias if the object in question has been seen before](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.4/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L118-L125) (based on `object_id`).

Comment: If you implement your own `Visitor` without aliases watch out for circular references!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to perform a deep clone of the object being dumped to YAML. This is because YAML will identify the anchors and aliases based on their identity, and if you `clone` or `dup` them, the new object will be equal, but have a different identity.

There are many ways to perform a deep clone, including library support, or writing your own helper function -- I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

One simple (hacky) approach I used was convert the yaml to json. and then convert it back to YAML. new YAML does not contain aliases/anchors.

```
require 'json'

jsonObj = oldYaml.to_json
newYaml = YAML.load(jsonObj)
print newYaml.to_yaml
```